# Possible to load SVG files with Browserify

Tags: javascript, svg, browserify

Trying to require an svg with the this line:

```
var framea = require('../images/frames/text-frame-one.svg');
```

… and getting this error when compiling:

```
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token
```

The SVG is incredibly simple and shouldn't be the cause of any errors. Is there a way to load an SVG reliably with Browserify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found **[svgify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svgify)** but had forgotten to add it to my package.json as a transform:

```
"browserify": {
  "transform": ["svgify"]
}
```